# Use jQuery UI Layout to make 2x2 panels

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-layout

I'm trying to make a clone of jsfiddle. This is a 2x2 layout. I found jQuery-UI Layout which works perfectly... accept it seems to require a "center" pane, which doesn't exist in a 2x2 layout.

How can I disable the "center" pane? Or how can I make a 2x2 panel layout using "jQuery UI-layout" or another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Simply consider one of your "column" as center pane, and then divide it horizontally in two sub-panes. You have to think it such as a "nested" layout.